# What is the (id) mean in the init method?

Tags: objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the meaning of id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7987060/what-is-the-meaning-of-id)

I am the newbie to Ios programming.

I saw the following declaration

```
- (id)init
```

what does (id) mean here?

Answer (score 6):

`id` denotes a type which is compatible with any object. The notation

```
- (id)init
```

means the `init` instance method of your class; typically it's used to initialize the instantiated object after memory allocation (usually done using `alloc`). In Objective-C, methods' return type is declared by putting the type in parentheses before the method name. So, here it means that the `init` method may return any Objective-C object.

---

But you should really, really google an Objetive-C tutorial and read it. This is such a fundamental thing for which there is **no excuse** for not reading a tutorial or other documentation.

Answer (score 1):

`id` is the plain C compatible type that represents an Objective-C object. This allows C source code to store, and interact with, Objective-C objects.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for it to be of type 'id' is that the -init method is inherited all the way up from NSObject (in objective-C you can not overload methods, hence you can not change the argument/retrurn value types when subclassing). Since 'id' works with any object, this is OK.

**EDIT** It seems that specifying a concrete class as the return type of -init is OK, even though you are ultimately overriding '-[NSObject init]'.

I guess the use of 'id' is just a custom?

The fact that 'id' acts as a "generic Objective-C object pointer" that accepts any object type on assignment remains unchanged, though.

Comment: You can indeed change the classes of return and argument types when subclassing.

Comment: "you can not change the argument/retrurn value types when subclassing" This is not true, actually. Haven't you seen things like `- (MyViewController *)init`?

Comment: You are right, I stand corrected. What I'm sure you can not do is subclass a property accessor with one specifying a subclass of the original type. (but of course that is not relevant to the question)

Comment: ...So, why do we keep using 'id' over and over, again? :)

Comment: Additionally, this article: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_Inheritance seems to validate my initial claim... So which one is it?

Answer (score -1):

-(id)init is called to initialize the variables inside an object and do any necessary setup (it's basically the constructor).

A possiable duplication can be
[What's the -(id)init method good for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887062/whats-the-idinit-method-good-for)

Comment: This doesnt answer the question